# awk code to collapse rows and keep the whole line based on one column's value

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I'm trying to write an awk script to collapse identical rows (defined by several columns) and keep the whole line that has the minimum value.

This is my example input:

```
A     20    30     Boston     US     3     tempCity     top
A     20    30     London     UK     2     coldCity     top
A     20    30     Singapore      SG     4      hotCity     top
B     10    20     Tokyo      JP     3     coldCity     mid
```

I would like to keep only one row with the minimum value of sixth column, if the first, second, third and eighth columns are the same. This is my expected output:

```
A     20    30     London     UK     2     coldCity     top
B     10    20     Tokyo      JP     3     coldCity     mid
```

I have tried to write this code:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{par=$1 OFS $2 OFS $3 OFS $8} $6<a[par]{a[par]=(par in a)?a[par]$0:$0} END {for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' cityList.txt
```

but I only got the following output:

```
A       20      30      top
B       10      20      mid
```

I'm a newbie in awk, so any help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there!

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '!a[$1,$2,$3,$8] || $6 < a[$1,$2,$3,$8] { a[$1,$2,$3,$8] = $0 } END {for (i in a) print a[i]}' file
```

I changed the condition on setting the value in the array `a`, so that it's set when the key is not defined or the value is less than the current key.

I've chosen to use `$1,$2,$3,$8` everywhere - you could set a variable equal to this using `$1 SUBSEP $2 SUBSEP $3 SUBSEP $8` if you want to avoid repetition. `SUBSEP` is a control character, which is very unlikely to clash with the contents of the key.

The loop in the `END` block only prints out the line stored in `a[i]`, rather than concatenating the key, which you were attempting to do.

Comment: Hi Tom! Thanks a lot! It solved my problem and I learned something new as well.

Answer (score 0):

alternative to `awk`, perhaps easier to read as well

```
$ sort -k6,6n cities | sort -u -k1,3 -k8

A     20    30     London     UK     2     coldCity     top
B     10    20     Tokyo      JP     3     coldCity     mid
```